# How to get image posted in facebook using HashTag - C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hashtag

In my application, I was asked to get the facebook feeds and the posted image using its Hashtag.

I have tried with the below URL.
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23test&access_token={Accesstoken}

I got the feeds, but the posted image are not showing up. Also the Access token is need to be generated all the time when i log in.

Please help to get the posted image from facebook using HASHTAG with any sample url or C# code.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Public post search is deprecated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: so is it possible to get the posted images from any other way???